File can't be attached react native share
I used react-native-share library to share PDF file using base64, It is working fine on android and iOS Mail but not working on iOS Gmail, its showing File Can't be attached
const options = {
            message: 'Message',
            title: 'Title',
            subject: 'Subject',
            url: `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64}`
        };


    Share.open(option)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });`

